# My JavaFX media player doesn't display videos in MediaView consistently

Tags: debugging, javafx, video, frontend, media

My JavaFX mediaplayer is not displaying videos consistently. Sometimes it works first try, sometimes it takes 3 or 4 tries. The buttons and the rest of the events do happen, it's just the video that's not being displayed/ linked to the MediaView. The file is being selected through a fileChooser and I think something tied to that might be the actual issue. I'll put the relevant code from my controller down below:

```
@FXML
    private void handleOpenFile() {
        // Create a file chooser dialog and set the initial directory
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
        // Filter for media files
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(
                "Media Files (*.mp4, *.mp3, *.wav, *.jpg, *.png)", "*.mp4", "*.mp3", "*.wav", "*.jpg", "*.png");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);
        // Show the file chooser dialog and get the selected file
        Stage stage = (Stage) mediaView.getScene().getWindow();
        openFile(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage));
    }
    private void openFile(File file){
        if (file != null) {
            this.file=file;
            // Check if the selected file is a media file or an image
            String filename = file.getName();
            String extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase();
            if (extension.equals("jpg") || extension.equals("png")) {
                // Display the selected image in the image view
                disableVideo();
                imageView.setImage(new Image(file.toURI().toString()));
            } else {
                // Create a media player and set it to the media view
                disableImage();
                Media media = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
                mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
                // Bind the time slider to the media player's current time
                timeSlider.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    if (timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.seconds(newValue.doubleValue()));}
                });
                mediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    if (!timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {timeSlider.setValue(newValue.toSeconds());}
                });
                mediaPlayer.setOnReady(() -> timeSlider.setMax(mediaPlayer.getMedia().getDuration().toSeconds()));
            }
        }
    }
private void disableImage(){
        mediaView.setVisible(true);
        imageView.setVisible(false);
        playButton.setVisible(true);playButton.setDisable(false);
        timeSlider.setVisible(true);timeSlider.setDisable(false);
    }
    private void disableVideo(){
        pause();
        mediaView.setVisible(false);
        imageView.setVisible(true);
        playButton.setVisible(false);playButton.setDisable(true);
        timeSlider.setVisible(false);timeSlider.setDisable(true);
    }
    private void pause(){
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            isPlaying = false;
            playButton.setText("Play");
        }
    }
    @FXML
    private void handlePlay() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null && !isPlaying) {
            mediaPlayer.play();
            isPlaying = true;
            playButton.setText("Pause");
            mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
                mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.ZERO);
                pause();
            });
        }else pause();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleTimeSliderChanged() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.seek(mediaPlayer.getMedia().getDuration()
                    .multiply(timeSlider.getValue() / timeSlider.getMax()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi there,

     1) check the encoding of the video with JavaFX encoding.

     2) check the video resolution, it can be too high

      3)check also media view layout settings. 

if problem still occurs, try to change the JavaFX library

Comment: [mcve] please .. mind the __M__ while at the same time being runnable as-is and reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there try following solutions:

1. check the encoding of the video with JavaFX encoding;
2. check the video resolution, it can be too high for the Media view
3. also see media view layout properties, double check its size.

If issue still exists try to change JavaFX library to another one. (also consider showing the entire source code for further discussions)